# Cannot use Response.Write in <head> section of aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, head, response.write

I'm trying to use the Response.Write() method to dynamically insert content in the < head > section of an aspx page. I need to inject a string value from a property on a code-behind object which is a link to my CSS file. However, it is not being processed properly at run time. The object is public on the class and is hydrated in the Page_Load() event. Down in the body of the page I can successfully inject other properties from the Corpoartion object with no problem at all.

Why does this not work in the < head > section?

This is the part that does not expand correctly:

```
<link href="<%= Corporation.PageStyleSheet %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Here is the entire < head > section:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="<%= Corporation.PageStyleSheet %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript" src="cntv_menu.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript" src="cntv_category.js"></script>   
</head>
```

What is the reason that this will not expand properly?

Comment: In case others stumble here, the accepted answer has a slight mistake: <%= %> CAN be used inside a <head runat="server"> element, I use it all the time for comment, <title> and <script> variables (only <link> and <meta> elements are known to be a problem).  I only needed to give the <link> element an ID= property then set the href property in code-behind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `<%= %>` inside a `runat="server"` tag, which your `<head>` tag is.

You can either change it to `<%# %>` and DataBind to it in the code-behind, or you can make the link tag `runat="server"`, give it an `id` and assign the attribute from the code behind.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177471/input-losing-src/2221091#2221091), which goes into the details.

Comment: Thanks. You got me going. < head > had runat="server" already, so it turns out I did not need to add that to the link, but I did give the link an id="csslink" and then in codebehind, I call csslink.DataBind(). Works like a charm!

Comment: I realize that this is nearly a decade old, but I stumbled across it and felt it was worth noting that `<%# … %>` can't be used inside of a quoted identifier within a server control (e.g., within `<head runat="server" />`). In those cases—as counter-intuitive as it seems if you're thinking of the declarative syntax as HTML elements—you must remove the attribute quotes. E.g., `<link href=<%# Corporation.PageStyleSheet %> rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`. This will still render with quotes around the attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
this.myButton.Attributes.Add(attribute, value);
```

It worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

the best way to resolve this problem is using **OnPreRender**

Example:

First, define your tag:

```
<link href="~/css/your_default.css" type="text/css" runat="server" id="myCSS" />
```

And on the OnPreRender:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e){
     base.OnPreRender(e);
     myCSS.Attributes["href"] = "~/css/your_new.css";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you write out the full line you should be ok:

```
<%
Response.write("<link href=\"" + Corporation.PageStyleSheet + "\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />");
%>
```

P.S. My syntax may not be completely right, sorry in advance.

Comment: That won't work for the same reason that `<%= %>` doesn't work. The code within a runat=server control is parsed as a server-control tree only.

Comment: Good idea for thinking outside the box (kind of), but, as stated, it still doesn't work. Sorry, man.

Comment: That's odd, because I have it working in a head runat="server"

Does ASP.NET runat Server work differently from MVC? or is it because my head section is inside a masterpage anyone know?

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't be using head runat="server" with ASP.NET MVC as doing so mixes control hierarchies (webforms) with MVC