# Head section link tag rendering issue

Tags: asp.net, render

I was using that (with head runat)

```
<link href="https://<%= AppSettingBase.AppSetting("CdnDomain")%>/cdn/css/iebutton.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

it was rendering correctly

```
<link href="https://cdn.mydomain.com/cdn/Content/css/iebutton.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

now I am using (with head runat)

```
<link href="https://<%= UIAppSetting.CdnDomain%>/cdn/css/iebutton.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

it rendering wrong , but without head runat working fine

```
<link href="https://&lt;%= UIAppSetting.CdnDomain%>/cdn/css/iebutton.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

What is difference between two, how can I solve it?

**Edit**

`UIAppSetting` is class and `CdnDomain` is static property and I added namespace in web.config

Comment: UIAppSetting.CdnDomain what is that?

Comment: UIAppSetting is class and CdnDomain is static property

Comment: is this static class? or you create an instance of this class on this code page?

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya: I made a new web project for testing this, but I don't have your issue. It works fine for me. Are you working on a web project or a web site? What asp.net version are you using? Can you post you web.config, so we can figure ou if there's something strange there?

Comment: guys sorry for late reply, @Gaurav : no need to create instance because CdnDomain is static member.

Comment: @themarcuz I am using web project and asp.net 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my issue but it is not good way I think. specially thanks to [themarcuz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333223/themarcuz), he tried well for me.

```
<link <% Response.Write("href='https://" + UIAppSetting.CdnDomain +"/cdn/css/iebutton.css'");%> rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2221091/333223) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2221091/333223) (which actually link the first one) states that you can't use `<%= %>` syntax inside a `runat="server"` tag, which your `head` tag actually is.
I also find some other pages on internet who state the same.

Given this, I don't understand why it works your first version

```
<link href="https://<%= AppSettingBase.AppSetting("CdnDomain")%>/cdn/css/iebutton.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: exactly I am also trying to find this answer,why it works my first version

Answer (score 0):

I've had something like this before,

does it work correctly if you substitute the

```
<link href=" blah blah " />
```

for

```
<link href=' blah blah ' />
```

single quotes instead of double quotes, i'm sure I had an issue once where it didn't like the fact that I had a double quote inside a double quote. no matter it's context (although it may have been in an Eval context)

Comment: I have already tried single quote but no luck.. anyway thanks.